# N1QL - How to add new field to each element of array which is inside another array?

Tags: arrays, couchbase, sql++

I'm new at Couchbase and I got this structure:

```
{ 
  items: [
    {
      id: "a1",
      subitems: [
        {
          id: "b1",
          name: "joe1"
        },
        {
          id: "b2",
          name: "joe2"
        }
      ] 
    }
  ],
  docType: "mydoc"   
}
```

I need to add new field to each object inside subitems. I know how to do this with 1 level array =>

```
UPDATE default SET a.newField='blabla' FOR a IN items END where docType = 'mydoc';
```

It will produce that:

```
{ 
  items: [
    {
      newField: "blabla",
      id: "a1",
      subitems: [
        {
          id: "b1",
          name: "joe1"
        },
        {
          id: "b2",
          name: "joe2"
        }
      ] 
    }
  ],
  docType: "mydoc"   
}
```

But I need this result:

```
{ 
  items: [
    {
      id: "a1",
      subitems: [
        {
          newField: "blabla",
          id: "b1",
          name: "joe1"
        },
        {
          newField: "blabla",
          id: "b2",
          name: "joe2"
        }
      ] 
    }
  ],
  docType: "mydoc"   
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the upcoming Couchbase 4.5.1, you should be able to do:

```
UPDATE default
SET s.newField = 'newValue' FOR s IN ARRAY_FLATTEN(items[*].subitems, 1) END;

UPDATE default
SET s.newField = 'newValue' FOR s IN ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY i.subitems FOR i IN items END, 1) END;

UPDATE default
SET i.subitems = ( ARRAY OBJECT_ADD(s, 'newField', 'blabla' ) FOR s IN i.subitems END ) FOR i IN items END;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using 4.1.0-5005. Is there something for this version?

Comment: Ok, I upgraded server to 4.5, both of queries give me same error 

"msg": "syntax error - at ("

Comment: Try typing the queries manually. You might have a hidden character in your copy and paste.

Comment: Still doesn't work. For now version is 4.5.0-2203. It doesn't work in cbq console and in web browser (admin console). And one thing I've noted is when I put query to web browser workbench I see that ARRAY_FLATTEN doesn't highlited like for example ARRAY or UPDATE or other else operators. Does it mean ARRAY_FLATTEN is unknown for this version? I think yes. Maybe you know some another way how to do that trick?

Comment: I added a third syntax option to the answer. They should all work in the cbq shell.

Comment: I don't see any relation to subitems array in third query, are you sure?

Comment: Yes, you should run the query.

Comment: Works but if "items" array contains other json objects it will add newField there also. It's incorrect. In other words third query adds newField to every json object inside "items" array. I need to add newField only to elements of "subitems" array.

Comment: You are right. Fixed in the upcoming Couchbase 4.5.1.